# How to iterate through enums with integer as value in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, enums

I have an enum

```
export enums Actions {
All = 1,
Success = 2,
Failed = 3
}
```

When I iterate through it using for loop, I am getting total of 6 entries. I get to know that this is how it works in Typescript. But how can I use the enum so that I can access

```
enum.key
```

for "All, Success, Falied" and

```
enum.value
```

for 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

What you can do in order to access the enum `keys` and `values` like you described in the OP is *convert* your enum to a basic object that has the properties `keys` and `values` with the corresponding data.

```
export enum Actions {
  All = 1,
  Success = 2,
  Failed = 3
}

export type ConvertedActions = {
  keys: string[];
  values: Actions[];
};

const result = Object.values(Actions).reduce(
  (acc, curr): ConvertedActions =>
    isNaN(+curr)
      ? {...acc, keys: [...acc.keys, curr as string]}
      : {...acc, values: [...acc.values, curr as Actions]},
  <ConvertedActions>{keys: [], values: []}
);

console.log(result.keys);    // [ 'All', 'Success', 'Failed' ]
console.log(result.values);  // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Note: Don't get confused by the extra type (`ConvertedActions`) I defined. However, it is needed to avoid using `any` a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) of typescript, if `as const` keyword suffices, then we dont need to use enum.

Just interpreting, maybe in this case an implementation like illustrated can be used, with `Object.keys(obj)` and `Object.values(obj)` to get the required outputs

```js
const Actions = {
  All: 0,
  Success: 1,
  Failure: 2
} as const

let keyArr = Object.keys(Actions);
let valArr = Object.values(Actions);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const keys = Object.keys(Actions);
const values = Object.values(Actions);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with and I think it's as intuitive as it's gonna get

```
for (const keyString in Actions) {
    const key = Number(keyString);
    if (isNaN(key)) { continue; }
    console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: An explanation always imp[roves a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, in this specific case, is separating `All, Success, Falied` and `1, 2, 3` in two different arrays.

```js
export enums Actions {
    All = 1,
    Success = 2,
    Failed = 3
}
console.log(Object.keys(enums).filter((v) => isNaN(Number(v)))); // ["All", "Success", "Failed"] 
console.log(Object.keys(enums).filter((v) => !isNaN(Number(v)))); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

You can also do it with a `for..in` loop:

```js
for (const value in enums) {
  console.log(value); // 1, 2, 3, All, Success, Falied
  console.log(value.filter((v) => isNaN(Number(v)))); // All, Success, Falied
  console.log(value.filter((v) => !isNaN(Number(v)))); // 1, 2, 3
}
```

There are more ways to do it using `forEach`, `for..of`, etc. But from your question I think my example should do the trick.