# Why is iterating enums so counter intuitive in typescript?

Tags: typescript, loops, enums, iteration

```
enum Direction {
    Down = -1,
    Up = 1
}

let i = 1;
for (const direction of Object.values(Direction)) {
    console.log('iteration ' + i++);
    console.log(direction);
}
```

> iteration 1
>
> Up
>
> iteration 2
>
> -1
>
> iteration 3
>
> Down
>
> iteration 4
>
> 1

I was expecting:

> iteration 1
>
> -1
>
> iteration 2
>
> 1

Generated js:

```
var Direction;
(function (Direction) {
    Direction[Direction["Down"] = -1] = "Down";
    Direction[Direction["Up"] = 1] = "Up";
})(Direction || (Direction = {}));
var i = 1;
for (var _i = 0, _a = Object.values(Direction); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var direction = _a[_i];
    console.log('iteration ' + i++);
    console.log(direction);
}
```

I'm sure there's a workaround but I really just want to know what causes this to go against every single expectation I had

Comment: Have you checked the generated JS yet?

Comment: [How to get names of enum entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372804/how-can-i-loop-through-enum-values-for-display-in-radio-buttons

Comment: TS enums aren't really meant to be iterated (or, from my experience, they really aren't meant for most of the things people try to do with them); you're running into [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), which are maybe helpful to some people, but apparently trip people up. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like what I'm looking for

Comment: @pink as I said I don't need a solution, just an explanation, which I guess is pretty much just you're not supposed to iterate over enums.

Comment: lol I was gonna ad an answer but got rate limited..? Anyways I was gonna link to [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119114/how-to-iterate-through-enums-with-integer-as-value-in-typescript/75987379#75987379) to get it to work.

Comment: The way I normally suppress reverse mappings is to check that the key is not a numeric-like string (since it needs to be a valid identifier to be a forward mapping), and that way mixed string-numeric enums are still usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at the generated JavaScript output:

```
var Direction;
(function (Direction) {
    Direction[Direction["Down"] = -1] = "Down";
    Direction[Direction["Up"] = 1] = "Up";
})(Direction || (Direction = {}));
```

We're only going to focus on the two lines inside:

```
Direction[Direction["Down"] = -1] = "Down";
Direction[Direction["Up"] = 1] = "Up";
```

Assignments are really just expressions that "return" the new value assigned to the target. So, after we assign `-1` to Down and `1` to Up, we assign `"Down"` to `-1` and `"Up"` to `1`, which gives us a reverse mapping that allows you to look up the name of an enum member:

```
console.log(Direction[Direction.Down]); // "Down"
```

Basically, your enum looks like this at runtime:

```
{
  "1": "Up",
  "Down": -1,
  "-1": "Down",
  "Up": 1
}
```

However, this behavior is only seen in numeric enums. For example, a string enum like this will not produce a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings):

```
enum Direction {
    Down = "down",
    Up = "up",
}
```

As for the fix, you can check if the value is a number or not:

```
let i = 1;
for (const direction of Object.values(Direction)) {
    if (typeof direction !== "number") continue;

    console.log('iteration ' + i++);
    console.log(direction);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgJ2AYwC5wPYigbwLABQUxsGA7tgLxQC0AjADSElQCqADlNXYQL6GEANsFRQ4XKHQDchAGYYEUABTIsAZ1EATRCnRYoGWVADyAIwBWugHQA3AIaCwwNUvhI0mEAEovuZiTgjJVQAT3ZgQyhtdz1sAEJKagAicAhTYAQk31UQdHBgGQJ-Yhy1DGErQQwAcyUAcjhUDLtYqDqoAGoxDo6vQpZS8uBKmqVo3U8+viA)

Comment: Oh no what a mess. Thanks! I cam up with a simmilar solution which I'm using now. Thanks for explaining and solving